# TweetSharp not retrive all tweets of specified hashtag

Tags: c#, twitter, tweets, tweetsharp

I'm using the TweetSharp dll to get posts from twitter of specific hashtag, so the method Search is not retriving all tweets of all time.

How to retrive tweets of all the time?

This is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> GetTweetsByHashtag(string hashtag, long sinceId)
{
    var options = new SearchOptions { Q = hashtag, SinceId = sinceId };

    var tweets = service.Search(options);

    return tweets.Statuses;
}
```

**EDIT**

I don't have any errors , the only problem is that is not returning all tweets, only returns the tweets from the  time near to the search time.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. What happens when it does not retrieve the tweets? any errors ? does tweetsharp have error handling?

Comment: @Gaetano I don't have any erros , the only problem is that is not returning all tweets, only returns the tweets from the time near to the search time.